# is there a way to prevent editing the url manually in Ember-cli

Tags: url, ember.js, ember-cli

In ember-cli is there a way to prevent the user from modifying or entering the url i.e, the url should change when the path changes (when transition occurs) but when the user tries to refresh/modify it - it should display 'page not found' or should redirect to the index page.
with some research i came to know that using `location: 'none'` in environment.js will not display the changed url. but what i want is that the changed url should be visible but the user shouldn't able to manually modify or refresh the url.

Comment: You can't really prevent the URL from being updated.  The whole point of storing params in the URL is so that users can maintain the same state when browsing back to that page.  Ember was designed to allow the URL to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply have your web server redirect all `404` (i.e. not-found) requests to `/index.html`. Then the visitor will not get a "page not found" but your app's homepage.